# notify top 10 leaders among friends

Tags: android, mysql, sql, facebook, leaderboard

Design/Development requirement: get top 10 friends of the user who has installed the app from facebook.Also is there any way to send notification to the friend if he is not in top 10 and when he is back in top 10 to send another notification.Is there any lib or functionality I can use.All the friends score is on my server .I really appreciate any help or providing me any material/links to achieve the above requirement .Thanks in Advance.

SUmmary: Facebook SDK+Android+get top 10 friends with pts which is on my server+notify friends when he has entered or if he was in top 10 and not anymore.

Comment: You don't seem to have run into a single problem so far. Do you need help populating the db? When it's populated you simply query it, sorting by score. Read up on the specific API parts as you go.

Comment: Ok basically I have all users points and users friends along with last  top 10 use's friends array and current users friends array And that is how I notify by sequence of insert /update and select queries which would be total of 5 queries everytime make some points.But I was thinking If there was anything simpler or any library which does this already.

Comment: Well 5 queries seems like overkill, but it might not be. Keep a list of friends with score and query it sorted by score, skipping the first 10. You might want to keep track of the lowest score in the top 10 so that you know when an insertion is about to move someone into the top. Or similar tricks.

Comment: You could've used [App42 leaderboards](http://api.shephertz.com/app42-docs/leaderboard-service/) which have specific Android APIs to do pretty much what you are doing through your own server like keeping global and facebook friend leaderboards. I've included a link - see if its helpful.

Comment: THis one looks good is there any inbuilt service provided by google/android or third party library along with my server integration avaibale out there?